# How to fix corupted MySQL installation

Tags: mysql, server

Due to some issues with the server, a number of InnoDB database folders with ibd, frm and TRN files were deleted (only affects databases not really needed anymore). Currently MySQL service starts only with the following setting:
innodb_force_recovery = 5

Then it crashes every few seconds, here's an extract from the log file

```
2022-10-11 17:38:54 27975 [Note] InnoDB: 1.2.10 started; log sequence number 313646609430
2022-10-11 17:38:54 27975 [Note] InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 5 !!!
2022-10-11 17:38:54 27975 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2022-10-11 17:38:54 27975 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2022-10-11 17:38:54 27975 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2022-10-11 17:38:54 27975 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2022-10-11 17:38:54 27975 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2022-10-11 17:38:54 27975 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.10'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2022-10-11 17:38:55 7f1d2c06a700 InnoDB: Error: page 4087 log sequence number 315137164614
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 313646609430.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2022-10-11 17:38:55 27975 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table '"wp_website"."wp_options"' in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 34249.
2022-10-11 17:38:55 27975 [Warning] InnoDB: Allocated tablespace 34249, old maximum was 0
2022-10-11 17:38:55 7f1d2c06a700 InnoDB: Error: page 252899 log sequence number 471118864984
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 313646609430.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2022-10-11 17:38:55 7f1d2c06a700 InnoDB: Error: page 85552 log sequence number 471118895771
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 313646609430.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2022-10-11 17:38:55 7f1d2c06a700 InnoDB: Error: page 147803 log sequence number 471118895778
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 313646609430.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2022-10-11 17:38:55 7f1d2c06a700 InnoDB: Error: page 4 log sequence number 470722597051
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 313646609440.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2022-10-11 17:38:55 7f1d2c06a700 InnoDB: Error: page 13 log sequence number 315130852444
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 313646609440.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2022-10-11 17:38:55 7f1d2c06a700 InnoDB: Error: page 3 log sequence number 315130852367
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 313646609440.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2022-10-11 17:38:55 7f1d2c06a700 InnoDB: Error: page 22 log sequence number 315133587106
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 313646609440.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
InnoDB: A new raw disk partition was initialized or
InnoDB: innodb_force_recovery is on: we do not allow
InnoDB: database modifications by the user. Shut down
InnoDB: mysqld and edit my.cnf so that newraw is replaced
InnoDB: with raw, and innodb_force_... is removed.
14:38:55 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=8388608
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=1
max_threads=151
thread_count=1
connection_count=1
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 68216 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x1d46900
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7f1d2c069e18 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x35)[0x8bfd45]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x4a4)[0x65b074]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x34c700f7e0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x9a45b2]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x97e382]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x943807]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x9a236d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x9a2bfd]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x8e1729]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z15ha_rollback_lowP3THDb+0x87)[0x5a27a7]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z17ha_rollback_transP3THDb+0x4c)[0x5a256c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z19trans_rollback_stmtP3THD+0x29)[0x764a19]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THD+0x23d)[0x6d2fdd]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDPcjP12Parser_state+0x32f)[0x6d7a5f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16dispatch_command19enum_server_commandP3THDPcj+0xe28)[0x6d8978]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24do_handle_one_connectionP3THD+0xcf)[0x6a682f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_one_connection+0x47)[0x6a6957]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(pfs_spawn_thread+0x139)[0xadc7d9]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x34c7007aa1]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x34c6ce8c4d]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (7f1d04004f30): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 1
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
221011 17:38:55 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
221011 17:38:55 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
```

How can I fix the problem? Or at least create the dumps of a few databases I need?

Comment: Don't you have database backups you can restore?  If not, I'm afraid this may be a rather painful lesson.

Comment: @dcp we have some but not all